# Recovering / Importing missing IPython history after an upgrade

Tags: sqlite, upgrade, history, pip, ipython

I performed a `pip install --upgrade ipython` recently, thus updating my old ipython version to 0.13.2. Since then IPython started using an sqlite file for storing its history.

Apparently the old history file in $HOME/.ipython/history is intact, but not used. Instead a new folder `profile_default` was created with a `history.sqlite` file in it, but without importing any previous ipython commandline-history entries.

Any advice on what I could do to get my previous history up and running again or how to import the text-history into the `history.sqlite` database, would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly straighforward to iterate over the lines of the old history file,
and write a new session to the new history via the `HistoryManager` object:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
from IPython.core.history import HistoryManager

def migrate_history(old_histfile, new_histfile):
    """populate an IPython sqlite history from an old readline history file"""
    # shell = InteractiveShell.instance()
    history = HistoryManager(hist_file=new_histfile,
        # this line shouldn't be necessary, but it is in 0.13
        shell = InteractiveShell.instance()
    )

    with open(old_histfile) as f:
        # iterate through readline history,
        # and write to the new history database
        for linenum, line in enumerate(f):
            history.store_inputs(linenum, line)
```

This function [as a script](https://gist.github.com/6003365), which you can run once to get your old IPython history into your new one.